# How to display "The Many" of a One-to-Many on One Line

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, structure, many-to-one

I was provided 2 files, as two tables: 'VoterData' and 'VoterHistory' - What is the best way to accomplish my expected display?

EXPECTED DISPLAY

```
ID      | First Name | Last Name   | Election1 | Election2 | Election3
--------+------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------
2155077 | Camille    | Bocchicchio | 2016June7 | 2016Nov8  | 2018June5
2155079 | Manabu     | Lonny       | 2016June7 | 2016Nov8  | 
2155083 | Scott      | Bosomworth  | 2016June7 |           | 2018June5
```

ONE- 'VoterData'

```
lVoterUniqueID | szNameFirst | szNameLast
---------------+-------------+------------
2155077        | Camille     | Bocchicchio  
2155079        | Manabu      | Lonny  
2155083        | Scott       | Bosomworth
```

MANY- 'VoterHistory'

```
lVoterUniqueID | sElectionAbbr 
---------------+---------------
2155077        | 2016June7     
2155077        | 2016Nov8      
2155077        | 2018June5  
2155079        | 2016June7      
2155079        | 2016Nov8      
2155083        | 2016June7       
2155083        | 2018June5
```

Comment: When choosing tags, please include the database type you use. "SQL" by itself just isn't sufficient because syntax varies a great deal by database.

Comment: Your question is "**how to pivot**" and the methods to do this vary greatly depending on database. Also, if you expect the number of columns to vary, you will need "**dynamic sql**". Both these topics are already well covered by many answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Crosstab query

```
TRANSFORM First(H.sElectionAbbr) AS FirstOfsElectionAbbr
SELECT H.lVoterUniqueID AS ID, D.szNameFirst AS [First Name], D.szNameLast AS [Last Name]
FROM VoterData AS D INNER JOIN VoterHistory AS H ON D.lVoterUniqueID = H.lVoterUniqueID
GROUP BY H.lVoterUniqueID, D.szNameFirst, D.szNameLast
PIVOT H.sElectionAbbr;
```

Comment: Worked!! Brilliant solution. It worked for my other data points.